# Vim, how to make Netrw to replace current open file instead of split opening new window, when you press preview or create new file commands?

Tags: vim, netrw

Recently I've been using netrw. I've put these four lines on my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:netrw_banner = 0

let g:netrw_liststyle = 3

let g:netrw_winsize = 25

map <C-n> :Lexplore <CR>
```

And I can easily toggle `Lexplore` and browse through the files to edit them. In this mode when I press Enter on any file on left hand side Netrw, it replaces the file in the right hand side window with new file; exactly what I want.

Problems start when I want to preview a file with "p" command on netrw or create a new file with "%" command. In former case (Preview) it split to the new window but I want it again to replace the file in right hand side window just like when I press Enter to to edit the file. And in latter case (creating a new file) it replaces the Lexplore (Netrw in the left hand side) instead of replacing the file on the right hand side window.

Is there any way that I can fix these issues? I've tried a lot of Netrw commands but nothing gives me what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The "p" netrw command is mostly just pedit. So, assuming you don't already have a preview window, just press `<cr>` atop the file you want to preview and then :set pvw. That will make the window holding the file the preview window.

The second issue concerns "%" to create a new file. I'll think this over, but I think perhaps the better behavior is as you suggest -- keep the Lexplore window but open the new file in the editing window.

Please try version 171e of netrw which you can find at my [website](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is related to a [bug](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/9004) in vim. Once you use `:Lexplore` it apparently changes the `g:netrw_chgwin` option permanently, so whenever you try to pres `<CR>` in any netrw window, it will always open in a new window.